V4L2 loopback device as source for QML Camera component
System information:

NVIDIA Jetson Xavier NX (aarch64)
Qt 5.15 (qmake)
Cross compilaton using Qt Creator on Ubuntu 22.04

Problem Description:
I am using the Camera & VideoOutput QML components (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-camera.html & https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-videooutput.html) together with a v4l2loopback device. I use this device as a sink in my GStreamer pipeline (v4l2sink) and as a source for the Camera QML component. Every few seconds I get this message:
CameraBin error: "Failed to allocate a buffer"
This is a block diagram of my GStreamer pipeline:

The video that is streamed into the v4l2sink is captured using the Camera QML component.
This is the code for the Camera QML component (the QML component Loader - named liveViewLoader - is not included in this code snippet as this is not relevant for the issue in my opinion):
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtMultimedia 5.15

Item
{
    /*
     * If the video stream does not exist on creation, the camera will never work.
     * The Component + Loader circumvents this by reloading the camera components after a timeout has occured.
     * The video device itself has to exist before the start, though.
     */
    id:             wrappingItem
    anchors.fill:   parent

    property string videoDeviceFile: "/dev/video2"
    Timer
    {
        id:         cameraTimeoutTimer
        interval:   1000 /* in ms */
        running:    false
        repeat:     false
        onTriggered:
        {
            liveViewLoader.restart();
        }
    }

    Component
    {
        id: liveViewComponent
        Item
        {
            height: wrappingItem.height
            width:  wrappingItem.width

            id: liveViewComponentItem

            Camera
            {
                id:             camera
                captureMode:    Camera.CaptureStillImage
                deviceId:       wrappingItem.videoDeviceFile
                onCameraStatusChanged:
                {
                    console.log("Live view camera state changed to", camera.cameraStatus)
                    var liveViewRunning = (camera.cameraStatus == Camera.ActiveStatus);
                    // If the camera changed state, but it's not running, set a timeout to restart the camera via the Loader.
                    cameraTimeoutTimer.start();
                    if ( liveViewRunning )
                    {
                        cameraTimeoutTimer.stop();
                    }
                }

                Component.onCompleted:
                {
                    checkAndHandleCameraAvailability();
                }
            }

            VideoOutput
            {
                id:             videoOutputArea
                source:         camera
                anchors.fill:   parent
                flushMode:      VideoOutput.EmptyFrame
                focus:          visible
            }

            function checkAndHandleCameraAvailability()
            {
                // If the selected camera is not available, the camera will automatically select a different camera that's available on the system. This is a workaround to disable that behavior.
                camera.deviceId = wrappingItem.videoDeviceFile

                let videoDeviceIsAvailable = (camera.deviceId === wrappingItem.videoDeviceFile);
                if (videoDeviceIsAvailable)
                    return;

                console.log("Camera is currently using video device", camera.deviceId)
                console.log("AvlStreamHandler.videoDeviceFile: ", AvlStreamHandler.videoDeviceFile)
                console.log("Video device", wrappingItem.videoDeviceFile, "is not available.")
                liveViewLoader.stop();
            }
        }
    }
}

Question:
Can anyone give me a hint why I get the "CameraBin error: "Failed to allocate a buffer"" error message and how this error could possibly be resolved?
Best regards
B0bbyR4y

Note that nvv4l2camerasrc only outputs UYVY format. You may also specify framerate if your camera provides several framerate for the target resolution. You may add identity with property drop-allocation enabled. So from terminal, does the following work: gst-launch-1.0 nvv4l2camerasrc ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=UYVY,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1' ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2 ! identity drop-allocation=1 ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video2. Here using YUY2 for V4L node, you may change to BGRx, or adding videoconvert change to BGR but using more ressources.

@SeB the identy element with the drop-allocation property set to true is interesting. I will try this during the week and will post the result.

@SeB adding the identity element with the drop-allocation property set to true makes the issue even worse. Originally the error occured every few seconds. With the identity element the error occurs right after the Qt QML 'Camera' component is started. In regards to the nvv4l2camerasrc: this element is not the issue as streaming the video directly using the nvdrmvideosink works fine. But using the Qt QML 'Camera' component leads to the issue described above.
